# Difference between /Regex/gm and m/Regex/g in perl string matching

Tags: perl

Is there a difference between ($ipAddrResult =~ /Regex/gm) and  ($ipAddrResult =~ m/Regex/g) in perl string matching? When I google online I get explanation for second one and not the first one. The file I tried to edit has first condition.

Answer (score 12):

In the expression

```
/Regex/gm
```

The "m" stands for multi-line matching. In the expression:

```
m/Regex/g
```

The "m" stands for "match" as opposed to a substitution, which looks like this:

```
s/Regex/replacement/g
```

Because matching (vs. substitution) is the default, you can generally leave off the "m/" from the start of the expression. In other words "m/Regex/g" is just a synonym for "/Regex/g".

Answer (score 11):

The `m`s in different places mean different things.

Let's look at the second example first.

`m//` is the regular expression matching operator. As a shortcut, the `m` can be omitted, so

```
$foo =~ m/$pattern/;
```

is exactly the same as

```
$foo =~ /$pattern/;
```

The only time the `m` is required is if you want to use delimiters other than `/` for your pattern. You can do, for example

```
$foo =~ m!$pattern!;
```

or

```
$foo =~ m[$pattern];
```

and so on, but these all require the `m` to be there.

In the first example, the `m` after the regex is a *modifier flag* which tells the regex how to behave. The regex flags are documented in the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) man page, which has this to say:

> **m** - 
>   Treat string as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from
>   matching the start or end of line only at the left and right ends of
>   the string to matching them anywhere within the string.

So this:

```
$foo =~ /$pattern/m;
```

is the same as this:

```
$foo =~ m/$pattern/m;
```

and the same as this:

```
$foo =~ m{$pattern}m;
```

Comment: The `\m` modifier matters when your input contains newlines. For example: `"foo\nbar\n" =~ /foo$/` is false, but `"foo\nbar\n" =~ /foo$/m` is true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `m/regex/g` is syntactically equivalent to just `/regex/g`. That is, it doesn't activate the `/m` flag at all. Compare to `s/foo/bar/` which is not at all the same as `s/foo/bar/s`. The name `m` stands for "match" I believe.

Comment: A nit: that's semantic equivalence, not syntactic equivalence.

Comment: Hm, I'm trying to say that the initial `m` is optional and basically superfluous. But certainly they are semantically equivalent.